# Lucene sorted search with spaces and hyphens

Tags: java, lucene

Lucene 8.0.0

I have a field that I am indexing like this:

```
doc.add(new SortedDocValuesField("nameS", new BytesRef(name.toLowerCase())));
doc.add(new StoredField("name", name));
```

The values of name look something like this:

```
London-UK
Bristol-UK
Bristol-AUS
New York-USA
Washington-USA
```

So they have spaces and hyphens in it. However I can't seem to get my search to behave - it seems to give up when it gets to a space or hyphen.

The analyser I'm using for indexing and search is the `StandardAnalyser`.

I search using code like this:

```
String escapedSearch = QueryParserUtil.escape(search.toLowerCase())
Query query = qp.parse("nameS:" + escapedSearch + "*");
TopFieldDocs results = searcher.search(query, 100, new Sort(new SortField("nameS", Type.STRING)));
```

Where am I doing wrong to allow the search to work with spaces and hyphens? As an aside, I've called `.toLowerCase()` on the name when indexing and searching, is that standard practise?

Comment: Could you share a sample of source data showing the context in which these terms can be found?  The `StandardAnalyzer` (see [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_4_1/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html)) includes the `StandardTokenizer` - and also does `toLower` for you.  The `StandardTokenizer` breaks on word boundaries and also removes some punctuation.  See the "quick brown fox" example [here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Word_Boundaries).  So, to advise on analysis and tokenization, a bit of source data context may help.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that searching may not be harmed by how the `StandardAnalyzer` indexes things.  Your search uses the same analyzer as your indexer - so does the `StandardAnalyzer` actually make searches not work the way you expect? I should have asked that first.

Comment: @andrewjames - its not "blocks" of text that I am indexing, its the specific tokens provided. The documents come from JSON where each field is an exact token. So  you can imagine: `String name = "London-UK"; ...; doc.add(new StoredField("name", name))`

Comment: Is it the fact I am querying based on the `SortedDocValuesField` field which is a `BytesRef` - should I be querying based on field `name` and just using `nameS` for the sort?